# Image upload using httppost in android

Tags: android, iphone

Iphone code which used to upload image works,but same code try in android gives status code 200 but image not upload.

**Iphone code**

```
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/s/sz/mws/%@?%@", appDel.baseUrl, request, parameter];
    
    NSString *boundary = @"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY";
    NSMutableURLRequest *mutRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [mutRequest setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
    [mutRequest setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
    [mutRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [mutRequest setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(80,80));
    [img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,80,80)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 1.0);
    if (imageData) {
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"picture\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:imageData];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }
    
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [mutRequest setHTTPBody:body];
    [mutRequest setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
    NSData *postData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:mutRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    
    NSDictionary *resultDict;
    if (postData != nil) {
        resultDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:postData options:0 error:nil]; 
        
    } else {
        
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please check your network connection" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        
    }
    return resultDict;
    
}
```

**Android Code**

```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
            "<URL>");

    String boundary = "0xKhTmLbOuNdArY";

    httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).toString()
            + "/Camera/Test.jpg");

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.ic_lock_idle_alarm);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 60, baos);
    byte[] BitmapData = baos.toByteArray();


    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(800 * 800 * 4);
    // StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

    String p1 = new String(("--\r\n" + boundary).getBytes(), "UTF-8");
    String p2 = new String(
            ("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"picture\"; filename=\"Temp.jpg\"\r\n")
                    .getBytes(), "UTF-8");
    String p3 = new String(("Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n").getBytes(),
            "UTF-8");
    String p4 = new String(("\r\n").getBytes(), "UTF-8");
    String p5 = new String(("--" + boundary + "--\r\n").getBytes(), "UTF-8");

    buffer.put(p1.getBytes());
    buffer.put(p2.getBytes());
    buffer.put(p3.getBytes());
    buffer.put(BitmapData);
    buffer.put(p4.getBytes());
    buffer.put(p5.getBytes());

    ByteArrayEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(buffer.array());


    httppost.setEntity(entity);
```

Comment: any error? or log message?

Comment: httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data"); 
status code is 200 but image not update on server.

 httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="+boundary);


give status code 500